# How to change from EPSG:900913 to EPSG:3857 in Postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, web-mercator

I didn't use the '-E 3857' switch when importing the OSM data into postgresql using osm2psql.

I'm trying to set up a map server for the first time and I'm following the instructions from here: https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataWindows#osm-prep.

I read that epsg900913 and epsg3857 are basically the same here: [What is the difference between EPSG:900913 and EPSG:3857?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/what-is-the-difference-between-epsg900913-and-epsg3857?newreg=8b2dd8627e174f56a97a3567fe6c5b65).

How do I change/transform the spatial reference in the osm tables (i.e. osm_line, osm_point, osm_polygon, etc) within postgresql from epsg900913 to epsg3857 using a SQL command?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution here: http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html

```
--This will change the srid of the roads table to 3857 from whatever it was before

UpdateGeometrySRID(varchar table_name, varchar column_name, integer srid);
```

So for my database the table name was 'planet_osm_line' and the column that contains the srid and geometry is 'way'. the SQL query I ran was:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('planet_osm_line','way',3857);
```

I checked if it worked by running a psql query from the command line:

```
psql -U postgres -d osm -c "SELECT ST_extent(way) FROM planet_osm_line"
```

Data was returned

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little more control and a little more SQL:

```
UPDATE TABLE foo
SET geom = ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 3857);
```

The command updates the `geom` geometry column of your table `foo` with a geometry with transformed SRID.