# readFeatures is returning the wrong (or no) projection

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, openlayers

I'm trying to change my map from using JSON to JSON-P for the source of data from my GeoServer. Unfortunately, what should be a vector layer covering the entire North Atlantic displays as a point in the Gulf of Guinea--so a classic projection error. But I can't see what I'm missing.

*TL;DR: If I actually request the data from Geoserver using `SRSNAME=EPSG:900913` I don't have a problem, but I can't figure out why I didn't need to do that originally!*

The original vector layer is created by:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '//'+$(location).attr('host')+'/geoserver/SAHFOS/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SAHFOS:CPRStdAreasIntRes&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
});
```

and works fine. The 41 features fit exactly to the coastlines of a world map.
Trying to do it with JSON-P:

```
    var stdAreas = new ol.layer.Vector({
        // Source retrieving WFS data in GeoJSON format using JSONP technique
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function(extent) {
                $.ajax('http://domain/geoserver/SAHFOS/ows', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        service: 'WFS',
                        version: '1.0.0',
                        request: 'GetFeature',
                        typeName: 'SAHFOS:CPRStdAreasIntRes',
                        maxFeatures: '50',
                        outputFormat: 'text/javascript'
                        },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback:'callback:loadFeatures',
                    jsonp: 'format_options'
                })
            }
        })
    });

    var loadFeatures = function(response) {
        var source = stdAreas.getSource();
        source.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'}));
        var fmt=new ol.format.GeoJSON().readProjection(response)
    };
```

`fmt` **is** `EPSG:4326`,  so that `dataProjection` shouldn't be necessary, but nevertheless, the layer still ends up being a point in the Gulf of Guinea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the featureProjection when you read the features:

```
source.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
}));
```

Comment: I don't think that's true (because I didn't have to when asking for JSON, rather than JSONP), and in any case as I pointed out, when I explicitly ask GeoServer to send me `SRSNAME=EPSG:900913`, I don't need to specify _either_ Projection parameter.

In any case, the question is _why is it different_ between JSON and JSONP, not how to make it work--as you can see, I _have_ got it working.

Comment: When you ask for JSON the ol.layer Vector parse for you the json using featureProjection: view.getProjection()  so when you ask for JSONP you need to do the same

Comment: 2nd if your JSONP contains coordinates in EPSG:900913 so the dataProjection paramter must be EPSG:3857 .    EPSG:3837 is the official epsg for EPSG 900913

Comment: _"EPSG:3837 is the official epsg for EPSG 900913"_ is exactly why I don't understand projections.  Why on earth wouldn't EPSG:900913 be the official epsg...?

Comment: See this [conversation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/what-is-the-difference-between-epsg900913-and-epsg3857) and the history [there](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857)

Comment: Thanks for that! It seems senseless until you know that there were competing companies using the same thing but giving it different names.